# How can I add JavaScript code coverage to TeamCity?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, teamcity, code-coverage, chutzpah

I have Chutzpah running QUnit tests in TeamCity with the following command:

```
chutzpah.console.exe /path src /debug /teamcity /coverage /emma coverage.xml
```

The tests are executed and listed in the **Tests** tab for the build.

The file **coverage.xml** is created and imported using a build feature. TeamCity is reporting a successful import:

```
    [Ant JUnit report watcher] Successfully parsed
    [Successfully parsed] 1 report
    [Successfully parsed] coverage.xml
```

I cannot get the coverage report to be displayed in TeamCity.
How can I add the code coverage report to TeamCity?

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 main ways to post coverage information in Teamcity:

1. Teamcity Service Messages: Some coverge reporters came with Teamcity report capabilities. This is the best one in my opinion, because you can use Coverage Thresholds as build failure conditions: i.e make the build fail if coverage is below 60%
2. HTML reports: If your coverage reporter generates HTML reports, you can either store them as Build Artifacts, or you can create a custom build tab to display coverage information, you only need a index.html file for this: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results

Comment: I implemented the build report solution. It's a good extension point and got me unblocked, thanks!